# Separate column into three columns with grouping

Tags: r, regex, split

I have a column with Full names that should be separated into three columns just by spaces. The problem is that some full names contains more than three words, and 4-th and other words shouldn't be omitted, but added to third part.
For instance, `"Abdullaeva Mehseti Nuraddin Kyzy"` should be separated as:

```
| Abdullaeva | Mehseti | Nuraddin Kyzy |
```

I tried to split column with (`tidyr`) package as follow, but in this way 3d part contains only 1 word after second space.

```
df<-df %>%
    separate('FULL_NAME', c("1st_part","2d_part","3d_part"), sep=" ")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example

Comment: Do you have always `name1 name2 fname lname`  and you want `| name1 | name2 | fname lname |` ?

Comment: @shA.t, At almost most situation,yes, but I suppose it is possible situation, where I should group names in other way : `| name1 | name2  name3 | lname |` for another dataset (not in this one)

Comment: How do we know which way to group?

Comment: @Sotos, based on names count. If names number would be more than four.

Comment: What is the difference between `A |B C| D` and `A | B | C D` ? They both have 4 elements

Comment: @ЕвгенийМ please add more example names, and expected output.

Comment: Polad Bjul' Bjul' Oglý Mamedov splits into `Polad |Bjul Bjul| Ogly Mamedov`. But it's quite rare situation, so it can be done manually. Great thanks for help!

Comment: @Sotos 'A |B C| D E' - if full names contains more than 4 elements, 'A | B | C D' - if full names contains 4 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `extra` argument:

```
# dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(
  "some name1",
  "justOneName",
  "some three name",
  "Abdullaeva Mehseti Nuraddin Kyzy"))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  separate(x, c("a1", "a2", "a3"), extra = "merge")
#            a1      a2            a3
# 1        some   name1          <NA>
# 2 justOneName    <NA>          <NA>
# 3        some   three          name
# 4  Abdullaeva Mehseti Nuraddin Kyzy
# Warning message:
#   Too few values at 2 locations: 1, 2
```

From manual:

> **extra**
>
> If sep is a character vector, this controls what happens when
>   there are too many pieces. There are three valid options:
>   - "warn" (the default): emit a warning and drop extra values.
>   - "drop": drop any extra values without a warning.
>   - "merge": only splits at most length(into) times

Comment: What's that `extra = merge` business?

Comment: @Sotos black magic :D

Comment: Hihi...that dates back to the dark ages :) Nice argument  though. Merges all the remaining cols. I wonder if this can be utilized to address not-known number of cols (kind of like cSplit)

Answer (score 2):

Since for this dataset you said that you only have `name1, name2, last name`, then you can also use `str_split_fixed` from `stringr`, i.e.

```
setNames(data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(df1$x, ' ', 3)), paste0('a', 1:3))
```

Which gives,

> ```
>         a1      a2            a3
> 1        some   name1              
> 2 justOneName                      
> 3        some   three          name
> 4  Abdullaeva Mehseti Nuraddin Kyzy
> ```

**Note** that you can fill the empty slots with `NA` as per usual